# Haskell - Implementing function which extracts values from an algebraic data type

Tags: haskell, algebraic-data-types

Okay, as someone who came from Object-Oriented programming not a week ago, Haskell is somewhat overwhelming - its likely that this has been answered, but all my research has been fruitless. Please bear with me.

Say that I have two algebraic data types:

```
data Person = Person {name :: String, houseNumber :: Integer, hasBorrowed :: Bool}
data Book   = Book   {borrower :: Person, title :: String}
```

Now, I know that you can simply extract a value from a single algebraic data type with a function:

```
getHouseNumber :: Person -> Integer
getHouseNumber (Person _ houseNumber _) = houseNumber

getBorrower :: Book -> Person
getBorrower (Book borrower _) = borrower
```

My question is (and I swear I'm going to smack myself in the head when I get the answer) how would I write a function which extracts houseNumber (as an example) straight from book? In other words:

```
getHouseNumberFromBook :: Book -> Integer
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this is redundant

```
getHouseNumber :: Person -> Integer
getHouseNumber (Person _ houseNumber _) = houseNumber
```

since `houseNumber` is *already* defined automatically as a similar projection. We get this from using the record notation in the `data` declaration. That is, Haskell already automatically defines

```
houseNumber :: Person -> Integer
houseNumber (Person _ hN _) = hN
```

and there's no need to duplicate that. Similarly for `borrower` and other fields.

About the actual question, we can simply compose the accessors:

```
getHouseNumberFromBook :: Book -> Integer
getHouseNumberFromBook b = houseNumber (borrower b)
```

or, more idiomatically,

```
getHouseNumberFromBook :: Book -> Integer
getHouseNumberFromBook = houseNumber . borrower
```

This is so short that one can probably use its definition directly, without having to define a custom function.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The fields of records are actually functions that extract a value from an ADT. So you have `borrower :: Book -> Person` and `houseNumber :: Person -> Integer`. Therefor you can use the composition operator `.` to create a new function `houseNumber . borrower :: Book -> Integer`.